How can two laravel docker services communicate?
I have two docker laravel services app1 app2 and I want them to connect with each other. So I have a docker-compose:
version: '3.8' 
 
services: 
  app1: 
    build: 
      context: ./my-laravel-app 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    image: laravel-app 
    container_name: tasks 
    working_dir: /var/www/app1
    volumes: 
      - ./my-laravel-app:/var/www/app1
    networks: 
      - laravel
    
 
  app2: 
    build: 
      context: ./team_members 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    image: laravel-app2
    container_name: team_members 
    working_dir: /var/www/app2
    volumes: 
      - ./team_members:/var/www/app2
    networks: 
      - laravel 

  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest 
    container_name: nginx 
    ports: 
      - "8081:81" # app2
      - "8090:90" # app1
    volumes: 
      - ./my-laravel-app:/var/www/app1
      - ./team_members:/var/www/app2
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
    networks: 
      - laravel 
    depends_on: 
      - app1
      - app2
 
  postgres: 
    image: postgres:13 
    container_name: postgres 
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_DB: tasks 
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: qwerty22 
    volumes: 
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    networks: 
      - laravel 
 
networks: 
  laravel: 
    driver: bridge
 
volumes: 
  pgdata: 
    driver: local

nginx config file:
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/app2/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass app2:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 90;

    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/app1/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass app1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

And from app1 I do responce to app2:
$response = $client->get('http://app2:81/team_member/names');

But I have this mistake? when I try to load page
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to app2 port 81 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://app2:81/team_member/names

So how I can fix it? My laravel apps can connect without docker
I tried to responce to app2 by different ways like localhost:81, but I still have the mistake.

app1 and app2 are your PHP-FPM services. If you want http access you should use the nginx container and the appropriate port (e.g. http://nginx:90/team_member/names). Personally I'd recommend using a single port for nginx and serve each app using a different server name

Personally, I'd forget that these are docker and just treat them as two regular websites. In order for App 1 to talk to App 2, it needs a host name which means DNS, it needs to have a firewall route accounted for (which is probably already open) and it needs to be able to validate the certificate, and that's usually just the common trust chain. I'm not saying to drop docker, btw, just ignore it from the perspective of the sites.

It works with http://nginx:90/team_member/names. I just needed to do a response through NGINX.
